# iOS remote notification display issue for both when app in foreground and background in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, firebase-notifications, react-native-firebase

I am trying to show the remote notification for ios/iphone irrespective of app state running or killed. I've used [react-native-firebase](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase)
library for this.

**Case 1: Key is "notification" and App is in Background (Killed)**

So when app is in background and sending the following payload, it shows notification just fine. But does not show notification when app is in foreground (App is running).

```
"notification": {   
    "alert" : "Alert, You have a notification", 
    "title" : "Notification title", 
    "body"  : "The body of the notification",   
    "sound" : "default" 
}
```

**Case 2: Key is "data" and App is in Foreground (App is Running)**

So when app is in foreground and sending the following payload, it shows notification just fine. But does not show notification when app is in background (App is killed).

```
"data": {   
    "alert" : "Alert, You have a notification", 
    "title" : "Notification title", 
    "body"  : "The body of the notification",   
    "sound" : "default" 
}
```

**Case 3: When Both keys set, "notification" and "data"**

So when app is in the background (killed) and sending the following payload, it shows notification just fine. But does not show a notification when app is in foreground (App is running). Ideally, for the following payload, it should show notification in both case, but it does not.

```
"notification": {   
    "alert" : "Alert, You have a notification", 
    "title" : "Notification title", 
    "body"  : "The body of the notification",   
    "sound" : "default" 
},
"data": {   
    "alert" : "Alert, You have a notification", 
    "title" : "Notification title", 
    "body"  : "The body of the notification",   
    "sound" : "default" 
}
```

What i want to achieve is, irrespective of app is in either of foreground or background, notification must be displayed when sent.

Here is the [link to the code](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1SJo_1dU5DBVWHZgUgrUt0YaRzn-BtC03tsdUR7kOJ3Q/edit): 
Please suggest.

Comment: please include some code samples

Comment: @tvankith I've added link to the code.